# Helicity is Conserved

Tags: calculus, fluid-dynamics

In fluid mechanics, the helicity is defined as 
$$\int_{R^3} u(x,t)\cdot \omega(x,t),$$
where $u(x,t)$ is a smooth solution of the Euler equations
$$\partial_tu + (u \cdot \nabla) u = -\nabla p$$ $$\nabla \cdot u = 0,$$ 
and $\omega$ is the vorticity $\omega = \nabla \times u$.  We need to show that helicity is a conserved quantity.

What I tried to do:  We also have the Euler equations in vorticity form $$\partial_t \omega + ((u\cdot \nabla )\omega) = (\omega \cdot \nabla)u.$$

So, if we write in component form, and then multiply the first equation by $\omega_j$, the second equation by $u_j$, and then sum over $j$, the left hand side has a term $\frac{d}{dt}\int_{R^3} (u \cdot \omega)$, which is what we are trying to show is $0$.  But then the rest of the terms don't seem to cancel (I would also think some sort of integration by parts should help here).

Is there a different approach that you suggest works?

Comment: Isn't a local conservation law (in differential form) an expression of the form $\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} + \vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{j} = 0$? In other words, you don't necessarily have  $\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} = 0$ (or, in its integral form, $\frac{dQ}{dt} = 0$), unless the quantity of interest has no current density, i.e., unless it doesn't "flow". Put another way, I think what you want to show is that $\frac{dQ}{dt} = - \iint \vec{j}\cdot\vec{n}\,da$, rather than $\frac{dQ}{dt} = 0$, for an appropriate choice of $Q$ and $\vec{j}$.

Comment: @wltrup Conservation should mean that the quantity doesn't change in time.  That is, $\frac{d}{dt} (quantity) = 0$.  The quantity in this case is the helicity as defined.

Comment: I'd like to draw your attention to the first paragraph of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation) Wikipedia entry: *A continuity equation in physics is an equation that describes the transport of a conserved quantity.*

Comment: @wltrup Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrodynamical_helicity  "Helicity is the only known integral invariant of the Euler equations, apart from energy, momentum and angular momentum."  It should be an integral form.

Comment: I think we're both correct. The vortex lines are "frozen" in the flow, which is to say that they don't have a current density, hence $\vec{j} = 0$ and the local conservation law (the continuity equation) translates into a global conservation law. However, you could still write it in differential form by defining an appropriate helicity density, so it doesn't *have* to be an integral form.

Comment: @wltrup But the integral form is what I would like to show : D

Comment: Fair enough. My previous comments were merely an attempt to clarify what you meant by a conservation law, whether you meant local or global. As it happens, in this case, they're one and the same.

Comment: @wltrup Ok so how to prove it?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rate of change of the helicity is given by

$$\frac{dH}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} [u\cdot \omega]\,{\rm d}^3x = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\cdot \omega + u \cdot \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial t}\right]\,{\rm d}^3x$$

First we can use the Euler equation and the vorticity equation

$$\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial t} = (\omega\cdot\nabla)u - (u\cdot\nabla)\omega$$

to get rid of the time-derivatives. This leaves us with

$$\frac{dH}{dt} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \left[-\nabla p \cdot \omega - \omega\cdot(u\cdot \nabla)u + u \cdot(\omega\cdot\nabla)u - u \cdot(u\cdot\nabla)\omega\right]\,{\rm d}^3x$$

The first term can be rewritten as $-\nabla \cdot [p \omega]$ since $\nabla\cdot \omega = 0$ and for the rest of the terms we find

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{2}\nabla\cdot(|u|^2\omega) &= u\cdot (\omega\cdot \nabla)u \\
\nabla\cdot[u(u\cdot\omega)] &= \omega\cdot(u\cdot \nabla)u + u\cdot (u\cdot\nabla)\omega\end{align}$$

where we have used $\nabla\cdot\omega = \nabla\cdot u = 0$. Putting it all togeather gives us

$$\frac{dH}{dt} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \nabla\cdot\left[-p \omega - u(u\cdot\omega) + \frac{1}{2}|u|^2\omega\right]\,{\rm d}^3x$$

and the desired result, $\frac{dH}{dt} = 0$, follows by the [divergence theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivergenceTheorem.html).

Comment: sorry for being ignorant but what  is p in your solution ? I am not sure how you go from the vorticity equation to the third step in your derivation.

Comment: I do not understand the last step either. How dH/dt = 0 ?

Comment: @gansub $p $ is the pressure. See the Euler equation in the question. The divergence theorem says that the volume integral of a divergence is equal to a surface integral over the boundary. Here the boundary is "at infinity" so as long as $u $ decays fast enough to $0$ as $x\to \infty $ then this is zero (and it has to decay fast if $H $ is to exist in the first place).

Comment: much appreciate the detailed response. The question does not state the boundary is at infinity does it ?

Comment: @gansub That was an informal way of trying to explain the application. The domain is all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. One way to approach it is to integrate over a sphere of radius $r$ and then taking $r\to \infty$. In this picture the integral becomes a surface integral over the surface of the sphere and will be of order $\sim r^2 u^2(r)$ so if $u$ decays faster than $1/r$ then it will vanish in the limit (for which the boundary is "at infinity").

Comment: upvoted the answer

Comment: Can this conclusion be extended to be applied to the N-S equation with the viscosity effect?

Answer (score 4):

One way to write the Euler equation is via the so called magnetization variables (see Chorin, A. J.: *Vorticity and Turbulence*, or [http://faculty.missouri.edu/~stephen/preprints/mo_smpok.html](http://faculty.missouri.edu/%7Estephen/preprints/mo_smpok.html))
$$ \frac{\partial m}{\partial t} = - u \cdot \nabla m - m \cdot (\nabla u)^T = -\mathcal L_u^{(1)} m ,$$
where $u$ can be computed from $m$ via the Hodge decomposition $m = u + \nabla q$, where $\nabla \cdot u = 0$.  Here $\mathcal L_u^{(1)}$ represents the Lie derivative along $u$ of a 1-form.  Thus, taking curls (equivalently the $d$ operator on exterior forms), we get the equation
$$ \frac{\partial w}{\partial t} = -\mathcal L_u^{(2)} w ,$$
where $w = \text{curl} \, m = \text{curl} \, u = dm$.  Here $\mathcal L_u^{(2)}$ represents the Lie derivative along $u$ of a 2-form.

Since we are in 3D, and since the flow is incompressible, the Hodge duality naturally identifies 2-forms with vectors:
$$ w = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -w_3 & w_2 \\
                   w_3& 0 & -w_1 \\
                   -w_2 & w_1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
   \leftrightarrow
   \begin{bmatrix} w_1\\w_2\\w_3\end{bmatrix} =: \tilde w. $$
Here we denote the vorticity as a 2-form by $w$, and the vorticity as a vector as $\tilde w$.  Then
$$ \frac{\partial \tilde w}{\partial t} = - \mathcal L_u \tilde w = - u \cdot \nabla \tilde w + \tilde w \cdot \nabla u .$$
Here $\mathcal L_u$ represents the Lie derivative along $u$ of a vector.

Next, we see that $m \cdot \tilde w = m \wedge w$ is a three form, which in 3D naturally identifies with scalar functions.  (Actually volume forms, but since the flow is incompressible this is the same as a scalar function.)  Thus $m \cdot \tilde w$ obeys the simple transport equation
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (m \cdot \tilde w) = - u \cdot \nabla (m \cdot \tilde w) .$$
The transport equation leaves the distribution invariant, that is,
$$ \text{measure}\{x:(m(x,t) \cdot \tilde w(x,t)) \in A\} $$
is constant in time for any Borel set $A$.  In particular
$$ H = \int_{\mathbb R^3} m \cdot \tilde w  $$
is constant in time.
But
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^3} (\nabla q) \cdot \tilde w = 0$$
because $\nabla \cdot \tilde w = d(dm) = 0$.  Hence
$$ H = \int_{\mathbb R^3} u \cdot \tilde w  $$
is actually the helicity.

Comment: Really beautiful answer. +1

Comment: Unfortunately, I know very little differential geometry.